# Passing arguments in Angular 6 e2e testing

Tags: protractor, angular6

With Angular 5 there is way to pass any number of arguments while executing e2e tests:

```
ng e2e --serve false "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"
```

These arguments reachable in `e2e.spec.ts` file through `NodeJS.Process.argv[]` array.

With Angular 6 all the additional arguments are ignored. After googling I haven't found any tips why it stopped to work and how to make it work again.

Comment: can you please post your package.json scripts session run?